# What is the alternative way of DataFlow module for Magento2

Tags: magento2, dataflow

Lot's of extension uses DataFlow module of Magento1 for data mapping and export/import product.

Is there any way to handle data mapping in Magento2 for importing product?

Answer (score 0):

Data mapping in Magento2 between systems and FTP can use DSYNC to apply attribute rules. Should use Dataflow or a migration tool for initial set up however if you require data attribute mapping on a regular basis DSYNC is an option.